# Copy variable value from a form to a class then to another form

Tags: c#

I have `form1`, `class1` and `form2`.

What I'm trying to do is to get a text from a textbox in `form1` and save it to `class1` and then again copy it to `form2` from `class1`.

Let me describe via code:

**class1.cs**

```
 public string username;
```

**form1.cs**

```
class1 user = new class1();
user.username = textbox1.text;
```

**form2.cs**

```
 class1 user = new class1();
 label1.text = user.username;
```

The problem is: When I try to call `username` variable in `form2` it returns blank. It just doesn't work. I dont know what I am missing.

Comment: It should not be surprising that `new` creates a *new* object.  So the user in form1 is a different one than in form2

Comment: Aside from your specific problem: It is conventione to a) start class names with uppercase letters (Form1, Class1, Form2) and b) avoid public fields and instead use properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you instantiate a new class1 in form 2, you won't never get your username in label1.

Comment: then what should i do

Comment: Please post you entire code. I suppose you have to put a reference of Form1 in your Form2 constructor, but I need your code to see what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The `user` in form2 is not the same one that in form1. So in form1 your `user` including a name, and in form2 it including an initialize value (blank). You can pass this `user` from form1 to form2 by Session or Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Make class 1 static. You will be able to call the class from any other instantiated objects, increment (or change) your variable and then retrieve it from any other objects. The synchronized part is something that stops two objects from accessing the incrementCounter() method at the same time. Something like this:

```
/* This class is thread-safe */
public final class CountHits {
  private static int counter;
  private static final Object lock = new Object();

  public void incrementCounter() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  public int getCounter() {
     return counter;
  }
}
```